# why would this return null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

i have this request that belongs to a location

```
>> r = Request.find 11210  
=> #<Request id: 11210, artist: "Coldplay", song: "Amsterdam", venue: "someplace", showdate: "2011-02-23", amount: nil, user_id: 11, created_at: "2011-02-23 02:55:13", updated_at: "2011-03-24 02:55:13", like_reason: "Its Great", pledge: #<BigDecimal:1032f1850,'0.29E2',9(18)>, location_id: 243, charge_card: false, approval_key: nil, charged: false, paypal_email: "coldpl_1300920081_per@gmail.com">
>> r.location.showdate
=> Wed, 23 Feb 2011
>> r.showdate
=> Wed, 23 Feb 2011
>> Request.find_all_by_showdate(r.location.showdate)
=> []
>>
```

they are both date fields in the db...

I am currently using sqlite if that makes a difference

Comment: If you are using Rails3, what is the output of Request.find_all_by_showdate(r.location.showdate).to_sql

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with dates/datetimes, I typically do a `.to_s(:db)` to format the date in a way that will play nicely in queries. I'm not sure if this is the source of your problem, but that's where I would start.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the "raw" output from `Request.find 11210`, you'll see this:

```
showdate: "2011-02-23"
```

Granted that that's not the `r.location.showdate` but it should give you a hint. Try this instead:

```
Request.find_all_by_showdate('2011-02-23')
```

If that works then you just have a format issue.

Keep in mind that [SQLite stores everything as a string](http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q2) internally, it accepts the usual data types in column definitions but everything is a string internally; so, somewhere along the line, the SQLite driver is going to say:

```
r.location.showdate.to_s
```

and get

```
'Wed, 23 Feb 2011'
```

Then it will look for that string in the `showdate` column but it won't find it because `showdate` contains dates in [ISO-8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).